# Symbolic computations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-expressions

How can I do symbolic computations in mathematica? I do not want to give a value to *any* Variable. Can I use Mathematica to create a set of equations, consisting only of symbolic variables, and then combine them, or solve by one specific variable?

If this were good, it could pretty much replace a paper sheet for doing mathematics.

It would be awesome if you could provide some examples. I hope the question is clear

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/?source=nav

Comment: Polite suggestion: edit your post to include a simple specific example input you would like to give Mathematica, the equations you would like it to create create from that, how you would like it to combine those equations, how you would like it to solve by one specific variable and what the result would be. Make it clear enough that, no matter what the answer is, it will be the answer you need. Make it simple, but not so simple that when someone answers you immediately respond with "yes, but that isn't what I actually want to do." Readers don't know what you have been doing or thinking.